# How can I fix chipped paint from the wall?

Tags: repair, paint

I've gone and accidentally scratched the paint off my wall. It annoys me. The scratch isn't big, but if I can see it I'm sure everyone can see it. Is there an easy way to fix this chip/scratch without having to sand and repainted the entire wall again. The scratch is tiny... but my OCD is getting the better of me and my eye twitch is getting larger the more I look at it.

[image]

Comment: My own OCD is making me twitchy too, just thinking about you thinking about the chip. Chill, over the years my wife has convinced me that just because I can see it *does not mean* everyone else can. Oh, and follow the advice of @isherwood.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to fill and level the patch with some spackle or joint compound (drywall mud). Carefully remove any loose paint first. Use a putty knife to press and level the material. Sand lightly when it's dry.

Then repaint, ideally with a small roller to create a similarly-stippled texture. Blend outward to better hide the new paint.

If you don't have paint on hand from the original job, you'll probably need to paint the entire wall, though you may not need to completely edge everything if you get a close match.